# Logical Complement Operator?

Tags: java, oop, boolean, boolean-logic, unary-operator

is it possible to use the logical operator "!" on object that holds a value of true or false? specifically for an object like this?

```
public class Briefcase {
    private final double amount;
    private final String model;
    private boolean removed = false;
    private String face;

    public Briefcase(double amount, int face, String model) {
        this.face = Integer.toString(face);
        this.amount = amount;
        this.model = model;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return face;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void remove() {
        removed = true;
        face = "X";
    }

    public boolean isRemoved() {
        return removed;
    }
}
```

then use it like this

```
Briefcase[] cases = new Briefcase[];
if (!cases[5].isRemoved()) { .... block of code}
```

is that possible? if so provide me links to that document that and some other examples, I find this weird at the same time interesting

Comment: The problem is that you're asking a question about an *array* of briefcases... not a single item. How to you expect that to work?

Comment: It would take less time to code and execute than it did to ask the question here and sit back.  Why not be an experimentalist?  Let the JDK tell you the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

The routine `isRemoved` **only** exist on the `Briefcase` object, *not* on the array. To use the negating operation **!** you have to try something like the following

```
for(BriefCase c: cases) {
    if (!c.isRemoved()) {
        // block of code
    }
}
```

Comment: let's say I made it as an array of object

Comment: @Andrew, The `cases` variable **is** an array. You could also write `!cases[5].isRemoved()`

Comment: !cases[5].isRemove() means? the opposite of it's boolean value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but not with array as shown in code but as `!case.isRemoved()`.

The point here is that **!(negate operatior)** works on boolean operands.

As long as the operand-expression resolves to a boolean **!** this will work.

Comment: There is no way and no logic how this could be applied to an array

Comment: negate operator means opposite of that? if cases[i].isRemoved contains false it means that !false? or not false?

Comment: Java Ka Baby, why array? Isn't it applied to a `boolean` member of a single element of an array?

Answer (score 0):

It is. `boolean` is a primitive type, but I see nothing weird with using `!`.

Comment: so what does mean? can you provide more examples? a much basic other than this? if I mean basic same usage on objects, not primitive

Comment: You cannot use it on objects. `cases[5].isRemoved()` evaluates to a (primitive) boolean, and `!` is applied to the result. It's just like `!anyBoolean` (more basic). Just as Suraj pointed out, you may add an imaginary pair brakets to the expression.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you left the index in the array by mistake or design.. but this will definitely work:

```
if(!cases[i].isRemoved()){ .... block of code}
```

where i is the index.

Comment: negate operator means opposite of that? if cases[i].isRemoved contains false it means that !false? or not false?

Comment: yes. "cases[i].isRemoved contains false it means that !false" is correct

Answer (score 0):

In this case ! negates the value of the call isRemoved()
You can have a look here to see the list of operators: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/what-is-java-operator-precedence.html

Also regarding the answer that said you can't write:

```
Briefcase[] cases = new Briefcase[];
if (!cases[5].isRemoved()) { .... block of code}
```

[] and . () operators have the same precedence.

The [] index operator will perform first because the line is evaluated from left to right, thus retrieving a Briefcase instance, on which you can call the isRemoved() method.